# When look up my character moves forwards in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this movement code with a box collider in unity (I am quite a beginner)

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float speed = 10.0f;
 
     void Update()
     {
 
         float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
 
         transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

And this mouselook code

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Mouselook : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float sensitivity = 100.0f;
     public float clampAngle = 80.0f;
 
     private float rotX = 0.0f;
     private float rotY = 0.0f;
 
     void Start()
     {
         Vector3 rot = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
         rotX = rot.x;
         rotY = rot.y;
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
         Cursor.visible = false;
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
         float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
 
         rotX += mouseY * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
         rotY += mouseX * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
 
         rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);
 
         Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);
         transform.localRotation = localRotation;
     }
 }
```

I tried making a different movement code and I was expecting it to let me use wasd to move in a unity puzzle game.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

uses local space and since your object is rotated and looking up it will start to move upwards as well.

You could eliminate that by using global space and erase any movement on Y by doing e.g.

```
var move = transform.rotation * new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
move.y = 0f;
transform.position += move;
```

Comment: It still moves forward when I look up (and backward when I look down), Would it be something to do with the collider